"bluetoothctl info" not showing battery percentage anymore after switching from X to Wayland
As the title says, after switching from X to Wayland (on the login screen), bluetoothctl info does not include the battery percentage of my headphones anymore. The line in the output is just gone. When I switch back to X, the line is there again. How do I get it back and why does the the choice of display server even have any impact on bluetooth?
The battery percentage is showing on X because I enabled it in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf by setting Experimental = true.
I am on Ubuntu 23.10.
